# Terminal Symbol vs Token in Lex or Flex

Tags: yacc, flex-lexer, lex

I am studying YACC and the concept of a terminal symbol vs a token keeps coming up. Could someone explain to me what the difference is or point me to an article or tutorial that might help?

Comment: See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are really two names for the same thing, but usually "terminal" is used to describe what the parser is working with, while "token" is used to describe the corresponding sequence of symbols in the source.

In a parser generator like `yacc`, the grammar of the language is defined in terms of an "alphabet" of "terminals". The word "alphabet" is a little confusing because they are strings, not letters. But from the parser's perspective, every terminal is an indivisible unit indistinguishable from any other use of the same kind of terminal. So the source code:

```
total = 17 + subtotal;
```

will be presented to the parser as something like:

```
ID EQUALS NUMBER PLUS ID SEMICOLON
```

There is a correspondence between the stream of terminals which the parser sees and substrings of the input language. So we say that the "token" `total` is an instance of the "terminal" `ID`. There may be an unlimited number of potential tokens corresponding to a given terminal (or they may be just one, as with the terminal `EQUALS`) but what the parser actually works with is a smallish finite set of terminals.